# checkbox checked property not working

Tags: css, checkbox, checked

I am trying to replicate [this](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/c/checked/) example but for a specific element, in this case the body but it doesn't seem to be working:

```css
#ossm:checked + label ~ body {
  color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="ossm" name="ossm">
<label for="ossm">CSS is Awesome</label>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wvkphx2o/1/

Comment: And, to be clear, the `<body>` is not a sibling to any element that appears inside of the `<body>` tag itself. Incidentally, do you know what those combinators that you're trying to use *are*, or was it just an optimistic attempt?

Comment: @DavidThomas is correct. The selector you are currently using is pretty much useless. Here   you have something to read: http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#combinators and also this: http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/

Answer (score 0):

In order to apply css to the sibling which comes after a particular selector we need to use either ~ or + (sibling selectors).

In the above case if you want to change the color of label text when the checkbox is checked, then you have to work this the following code.

**CSS**

```
#ossm:checked + label, #ossm:checked ~ label {
  color: #00ff00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As @DavidThomas mention in his comment you don't use `~` selector correctly. The only think i can imagine you want to achieve is this way:

```css
#ossm:checked ~ div {
    background: #f00;
}
#ossm {
    position: relative;
    z-index:2;
}
div {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="ossm" name="ossm">
<label for="ossm">CSS is Awesome</label>
<div></div>
```

Placing a `div` with `position: absolute` that overlay entire body.